# Warning: (1265, "Data truncated for column 'Date' at row 1")

Tags: python, mysql, python-3.x, date, warnings

I am using python3 to insert few values into a mysql database. I need to enter a name followed by three columns of numericals(around 15 digit numbers) , then another column that has the date in it.

Below is my python code.

```
today = datetime.date.today()
datestr = str(today.month)+"/"+str(today.day)+"/"+str(today.year)

connection = pymysql.connect(host='localhost', user='root', password='', db='testdb')

for item in resp['result']:
    data = (item['name'], item['numberone'], item['numbertwo'], item['numberthree'], item['numberfour'], datestr)
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    sql = ('INSERT INTO testdb.testtable (`Name`, `Col1`, `Col2`, `Col3`, `Col4`, `Date`) VALUES (%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)')
    cursor.execute(sql, data)


connection.close()
```

But I get the below error.

```
Python36\lib\site-packages\pymysql\cursors.py:165: Warning: (1265, "Data truncated for column 'Date' at row 1")
result = self._query(query)
[Finished in 0.7s]
```

if I print the variable data inside the loop. I get the below output. This is just to show you the type of data that I am trying to insert into the table.

```
('Myname', 169324790808576, 167102568398848, 2222222409728, 2222222409728, '4/30/2018')
```

I would like to insert all of these values inside the mysql database including the date. I get the error against the date. Appreciate help to fix this issue.

Comment: MySQL follows these general date formats yyyy-mm-dd or yyyy/mm/dd not mm/dd/yyyy assuming the Date column is date datatype.. little demo http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/96e79f

Comment: Perfect!. You are right. That fixed the error. Thanks a lot! :)

Comment: @RaymonNijland  A small follow up question. Now the code seems to run without any errors. But still, I dont see the date being fed into the database through the Insert command. Do you know what could be the reason. No change in the code from above. Just the date sequence has been changed based on your previous comment.

Comment: @RaymondNijland No worries. I fixed the error myself. I missed the connection.commit() function that must be written at the end of the for loop that updates the values into the  db. Thanks anyways! :)